# if pass and if continue in python

Tags: python, if-statement, continue

I saw someone posted the following answer to tell the difference between `if x: pass` and `if x: continue`.

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2]
>>> for element in a:
...     if not element:
...         pass
...     print(element)
... 
0
1
2
>>> for element in a:
...     if not element:
...         continue
...     print(element)
... 
1
2
```

What is the result for `if not element` when `a = 0`? Why when using `continue`, 0 is not printed?

Answer (score 37):

Using `continue` passes for the next **iteration** of the `for loop`
Using `pass` just does nothing
So when using `continue` the `print` won't happen (because the code continued to next iteration)
And when using `pass` it will just end the `if` peacefully (doing nothing actually) and do the `print` as well

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, `continue` is saying "next value in loop please"? And only "continue" if the `if` statement is `False`?

Answer (score 14):

'0' not printed because of the condition *"if not element:"*

If the element is None, False, empty string('') or 0 then , loop will continue with next iteration.

Comment: It isn't limited to `None` and `0`.  It will continue if the element is Falsey.

Comment: Does "if not 1"  mean False? Then why 1 is printed with continue? In addition, if someone writes "if None", it will also continue without printing? Thanks.

Comment: **1)** Yes. `if not 1` means `False`. In this case condition will fail and execution will continue with `print` statement. This is the reason for printing 1 in your code. `If not <some value>` will be `True` only if the value of `<some value> ` is any falsey values like None, False, empty string('') or 0.  **2)** `if None` means always `False`

Answer (score 8):

```
if not element:
```

In both examples, this will only match the `0`.

```
pass
```

This does *nothing*. So the next command, `print element`, will be executed.

```
continue
```

This tells Python to stop this for loop cycle and skip to the next cycle of the loop. So `print element` will never be reached. Instead, the for loop will take the next value, `1` and start from the top.

Answer (score 6):

There is a fundamental difference between `pass` and `continue` in Python. `pass` simply does nothing, while `continue` jumps to the next iteration of the for loop. The statement `if not 0` always evaluates to `True`, so both `pass` and `continue` statements will be executed. `pass` will do nothing and print the value, while `continue` will skip to the next iteration ignoring the `print` statement written below.

Answer (score 5):

From: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements

> The pass statement does nothing. It can be used when a statement is required syntactically but the program requires no action.

In your code snippet above `if not element` will evaluate to `true` when `element = 0`. In python `0` is same as boolean false. In the first loop `pass` does nothing, so it prints all three elements. In the second loop, continue will stop the execution of the rest of loop for that iteration. so the print statement never executes. so it only prints 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

`continue` is a control-flow statement used to escape the innermost body of iteration. When your code hits

```
if not element
```

the interpreter skips for all values of element that don't validate to`true`. 0 is one such value and it skips to the next iteration of the loop when it does not encounter the continue statement and therefore goes on to print the value of element `1` and thereafter `2`

In contrast, the pass statement does nothing but skip and return to the next line of code to execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
1 a = [0, 1, 2]
2 for element in a:
3     if not element:
4         continue
5.    print(element)
```

in the first loop, the value of *element* is 0, and (0 means False), if not False means True. That's why the condition is met, and we go into the if condition's indentation and read continue. When continue is executed, and it sends us to the next loop. In other words, first loop is terminated that's why print(element) is not executed. It results in not printing the value 0.

In the case of *pass*. It does nothing, when the interpreter reads the statement pass, it moves to the next line which is print(element) and it results in printing the value 0.